# Input checkbox doesn't work properly after the form is submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have tried adding:

```
   <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
   <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
   <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
   <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
   <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

And adding:

```
  'autocomplete' => 'off'
```

And adding:

```
  onload="document.getElementById('myform').reset()
```

On my form and html tags.

But still the checkbox doesn't work properly after the form is submitted.

What I am doing with the check-box is to enable/disable some inputs when it is selected.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#checkSpend').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
            {
                $('li.opcititycheckSpend').fadeTo(500,1);
                $('input.group1').removeAttr('disabled');
            } 
        else if ($(this).not(':checked'))
            {
                $('li.opcititycheckSpend').fadeTo(500,0.5);
                $('input.group1').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
    })  


    $('#checkRegister').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
            {
                $('li.opcititycheckRef').fadeTo(500,1);
                $('input.checkRegistered').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#inputFrom').focus();
            } 
        else  
            {
                $('li.opcititycheckRef').fadeTo(500,0.5);
                $('input.checkRegistered').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
    })  


    $('#checkTopup').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
            {
                $('li.opcititycheckTopup').fadeTo(500,1);
                $('input.checktoped').removeAttr('disabled');
            } 
        else if ($(this).not(':checked'))
            {
                $('li.opcititycheckTopup').fadeTo(500,0.5);
                $('input.checktoped').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
    })
    cache: false
});
```

It works properly when I reload the page.

How to make them working properly again after the form is submitted. (Because after the form is submitted, it goes to the page which has the template of the form again to resubmit the form.)

Comment: Use .prop() instead of .attr() like `$('input.checktoped').prop('disabled', false);` instead of `$('input.checktoped').removeAttr('disabled');`

Comment: @Arun thanks for the quick replay. but as you can see, I also have the function to fade an div `.fadeTo()`. And it doesn't fade the div after the form is submitted.

Comment: you reset the form, that's why the previous state was not save (it clears the form), need to populate it again based on the request parameters sent.

Answer (score 0):

*Edited:*

After adding the event handlers, try `trigger()`:

```
$('#checkSpend, #checkRegister, #checkTopup').trigger('change'); //triggers given event on page load
```

Remove this line:

```
 onload="document.getElementById('myform').reset()"
```